# How to use OpenLayer.Transform?

Tags: openlayers-2, coordinate-system

I want to draw a rectangle. The coordinates are somewhere in northern Germany. But the rectangle shows up in the Near East? What am I doing wrong?

```
       var epsg900913 = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:900913');
       var epsg3035   = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:3035');

       var p11 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(4281000, 3502000).transform(epsg3035, epsg900913);
       var p12 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(4595000, 3502000).transform(epsg3035, epsg900913);
       var p13 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(4595000, 4002000).transform(epsg3035, epsg900913);
       var p14 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(4281000, 4002000).transform(epsg3035, epsg900913);
       var p15 = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(4281000, 3502000).transform(epsg3035, epsg900913);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright, I found it out myself. The transformation of [EPSG:3035](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3035/) is not defined by [Proj4js](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/Documentation/Dev/proj4js), which is used by OpenLayers.

But it is possible to implement it by yourself.

1. Download [proj4js.js](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj4js/)
2. Include proj4js-combined.js to the HTML
3. Get EPSG code for proj4js: can be found at [spatial reference](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3035/)
4. Define it, in my case it looked like that:

   Proj4js.defs["EPSG:3035"] = "+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs";

[see also](http://www.polygongis.com/index.php/2011/05/02/proj4js-client-side-coordinate-conversion/)

Comment: +Very helpful and explained well

Comment: In the current version the syntax has changed, you now have to write: `proj4.defs("EPSG:3035", "+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs");`